# Automation of IE via VBA executes as intended, but throws an automation error

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, vba

I have the following code, which is supposed to open Internet Explorer in order to download a file.

```
Sub hentRapport()
  Dim IEapp As Object
  Dim WebUrl As String
  
  Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Set IEapp = InternetExplorer
  WebUrl = Oversikt.Range("Adresse")
  
  With IEapp
    .Silent = True 'No Pop-ups
    .Visible = True 'Set InternetExplorer to Visible
    .Navigate WebUrl 'Load web page
  
    'Run and Wait, if you intend on passing variables at a later stage
    Do While .Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Internet Explorer (IE 11.0.9600.17691) opens as expected, and [I get up the dialog for downloading the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlLYU.png), but at the same time I get an error from the macro:

[image]

The error happens on the line

```
Do While .ReadyState <> 4
```

and I can't figure out why. Doesn't that line simply state that Excel doesn't need to wait for IE to do its thing before accepting other input?

---

### Found a solution

After a lot googling, I finally came across [this page](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/excel-l/vba-how-to-eliminate-an-automation-error-resulting-from-new-version-of-excel-5396449), which contained a solution:

> The issue is related to IE8 and the Protected Mode: On feature. The purpose of this is to prevent malicious software from being run but it also prevents legit VBA code from operating. Depending on your work enviorment, disabling this may not be an option. Not to mention the general risks associated with doing that.
>
> I recommend the following solution.
>
> Instead of using:
>
> `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application&qu ot;)`
>
> use:
>
> `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium`
>
> You will need to add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls.

Now I just hope that all my users have that library :D

Answer (score 1):

How about something quicker? Using an API function that I believe IE is using, in order to download a file.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Public Function DownFromWeb(strURL As String, strFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim ret As Long

    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strFile, 0, 0)

    If ret Then
        MsgBox "Failed to download file", vbExclamation
    End If

    DownFromWeb = (ret = 0)
End Function

Public Sub TestDownload()
    Const URL As String = _
        "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/eab3ce1e413f1043da3a1574a0ab7360?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"

    Dim sDstFolder As String
    Dim sFullPathFileName As String

    ' get the destination of the temp folder.
    ' it should give you the path like you do in windows:
    ' Start-> Run-> %temp%
    sDstFolder = Environ("temp")

    ' add a "\" at the end of the destination path as needed
    sDstFolder = sDstFolder & IIf(Right(sDstFolder, 1) = "\", "", "\")

    ' combine the path with a file name to your choosing
    sFullPathFileName = sDstFolder & "360.png"

    ' This will try to delete the previously downloaded file( just in case)
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill sFullPathFileName
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (DownFromWeb(URL, sFullPathFileName) = True) Then
          ' Open the file (probably a windows popup will appear):
          Shell "explorer " & sFullPathFileName
          ' OR
          ' if it is an excel file, you could do:
          ' Workbooks.Open(sFullPathFileName).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

!!! By the way, if all you need is to download and open **an excel file**,
office has a built in option to do so (also with doc files in word). In such a case you might "get away" with a one liner like so:

```
Workbooks.Open("http://highlycited.com/highly_cited_2001.xlsx").Activate
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will give it a go tomorrow :) Can I get Excel to open the file from the temp-folder instead of saving it? It is just an automatically generated xls-file, which the user is going to look at some values in.

Comment: Hi, edited my answer. Make sure to check out the end of the answer- you might just need a single line of code, more or less.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion, which kinda worked, except the workbook was [kinda borked](http://imgur.com/76P7Bm2). My guess is that the company providing this service to our company requires us to actually be logged into their page to actually create a meaningful workbook (the URL is of the form "https://hydro.synergilife.dnv.com/hydro/report.aspx?fav=3602073&usr=xxxxxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxxxxx"). Will try your first suggestion next.

Comment: Sounds very interesting (never tried in such a https way). I'll be happy to hear about the result.

Comment: When using either of the methods which you've inserted at the end of the macro, I run into the same issue as when I simply used `Workbooks.Open(address)`, except I also get [this error](http://i.imgur.com/OQ1KArp.png). I think the problem may be that it is the aspx-file which is downloaded, while what I want is an xls-file which it redirects too, or something like that?

Comment: In that case, you might try to work the IE angle some more or opt for using an extenal tool, like wget, and call it from vba using : Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") to create a shell object that can wait for an external app to finish.

Comment: Finally found a solution, see the bottom of the question to have a look at it if you are interested :)

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not recognising the state specified. If you change the expected return it should run fine.

```
While .document.ReadyState <> "complete"
  'loop
Wend
```

See more [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp)

Comment: Attempting to change the code to what you suggest changes the error to `Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed`.

Comment: Do you have "Enable Protection Mode on"? It would be good as well if you added `IEapp.Quit` at the end of your module so excel doesn't run out of memory.

Comment: The option to enable protected mode is checked for internet, but not for intranet. I am pretty sure the site I want to download the file from is located on our intranet¨, so the answer is most likely no. If I add an `IEApp.Quit` at the end of the code, can't that close the IE-window before the download is done?